# Animating in 2D WebGL

Tags: javascript, animation, graphics

I'm attempting to animate a projectile's trajectory (in the form of a cannon ball) given an angle and initial velocity.  I've built the "cannon" in the form of a line and the target I'm aiming for in the form of a box, which I know is elementary but I just want to get the projectile motion down for now.  Currently, I'm messing around with hardcoded angles and velocity, but eventually would like to input the angle and velocity and have the cannon shoot following the input.  The target is parallel to the launch point, so I know that the x value of the cannon will be (initialVelocity)cos(angle)(time), and the y will be (initialVelocity)sin(angle)(time) - (g*t^2)/2, where g is the length or distance. Currently what I have is a cannon ball moving linearly across the screen, and it doesn't even start in the right spot.

I'm not asking for code to be written for me, I'd just like a starting point as to how to get the cannon to move from the right spot, and to know where I'm going completely wrong. I'm confident I can get it to hit the target if I'm taught how to manipulate the shaders correctly.

Shaders:

```
<script id="vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">

precision mediump float;

attribute vec4 vPosition;
attribute vec4 vColor;
varying vec4 fColor;
uniform float time;

void main()
{
 /*old code from manipulating clock hands*/
 /* fColor = vColor;
  float length = sqrt(vPosition.x*vPosition.x + vPosition.y * vPosition.y);
  gl_Position.x = length*cos(theta);
  gl_Position.y = length*sin(theta);
  gl_Position.z = 0.0;
  gl_Position.w = 1.0; */
  fColor = vColor;
  gl_Position = vPosition;
}
</script>

<script id="background-vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">

precision mediump float;

attribute vec4 vPosition;
attribute vec4 vColor;
varying vec4 fColor;

void main()
{
  fColor = vColor;
  gl_Position = vPosition;
}
</script>

<script id="fragment-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">

precision mediump float;
varying vec4 fColor;

void main()
{
  gl_FragColor = fColor;
}
</script>
```

WebGL code:

```
var gl;
var points = [];
var colors = [];
var cannonpoints = [];
var circlepoints;

var squarepoints;

var baseColors = [
vec3(1.0,0.0,0.0),
vec3(0.0,1.0,0.0),
vec3(0.0,0.0,1.0),
vec3(1.0,1.0,1.0),
vec3(0.0,0.0,0.0)
];

var program;
var backgroundprogram;

var Time; 
var thetaLoc;

var angle;
var initialVel;
var vx;
var vy;



var ballX = -0.5;
var ballY = -0.5;
window.onload = function init(){
var canvas = document.getElementById("gl-canvas");   

gl = WebGLUtils.setupWebGL(canvas);
if(!gl) {
   alert("webGL isn't available");
}

// configuring WebGL
gl.viewport(0,0, 
          canvas.width,canvas.height);
gl.clearColor(0.0,0.0,1.0,1.0); // set background color to black.

// load the shaders and initialize
// the attrbibute buffers.

  program = initShaders(gl, "vertex-shader", "fragment-shader");
 backgroundprogram = initShaders(gl, "background-vertex-shader",    "fragment-  shader");

   document.getElementById("shoot").onclick = function() {
    velocity = document.getElementById("velocity").value;
        angle = document.getElementById("angle").value;
        console.log("angle="+angle);
      vx = (Math.cos(angle*(Math.PI/180))*velocity);
        console.log("vx="+vx);
        vy = (Math.sin(angle*(Math.PI/180))*velocity);
        console.log("vy="+vy);

   }



Time = 0.0;
   thetaLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(program,"time");

   initBackground();
   /******************
   initBall(Time,1);
   *******************/
   initBall(Time);
   //render();
   setInterval(render, 100);
};

function render(){
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

     /* draw the circle */
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_FAN,0,circlepoints);
    /* draw the square(s) */
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES,circlepoints,squarepoints);
    //draw the cannon
    gl.drawArrays(gl.LINES,circlepoints+squarepoints,2);
    //draw the cannon ball
    //starting index is the amount of points already drawn
      //amount of points for circle + amount of points for square + amount of points for line
    var start = circlepoints + squarepoints + 2;
    Time += 0.01;
    initBall(Time);   //,1);
    gl.uniform1f(thetaLoc,Time);
    //amount of points to draw is length of points array minus the start index
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_FAN,start,points.length-start);
}

function initBall(Time) {   //,r){
   gl.useProgram(program);

    /*******************************************************
  filled_circle(vec2(r*Math.cos(Time),r*Math.sin(Time)),0.05,4);*/
    vx= (Math.cos(60*(Math.PI/180))*1);
    vy= (Math.sin(60*(Math.PI/180))*1);

  filled_circle(vec2(-0.8+(vx*Time),-0.3+(vy*Time)),0.05,4);

   // Load the data into the GPU
   var bufferId = gl.createBuffer();
   gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,                  bufferId);
   gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, 
                 flatten(points),
                 gl.STATIC_DRAW);

   // Associate our shader variables with
   // the data buffer.
   var vPosition = gl.getAttribLocation(program,"vPosition");
   gl.vertexAttribPointer(vPosition,2,gl.FLOAT,false,0,0);
   gl.enableVertexAttribArray(vPosition);

   // load color data to the gpu
   var cBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
   gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,
                 cBuffer);
   gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,
                 flatten(colors),
                 gl.STATIC_DRAW);

   var vColor = gl.getAttribLocation(
                program, "vColor");
   gl.vertexAttribPointer(vColor,3,
                gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
   gl.enableVertexAttribArray(vColor);

}
```

Comment: This isn't really a WebGL question. WebGL is just a rasterization/drawing library. In Javascript you'd compute a position, orientation, whatever, then draw. You might draw with HTML Elements, or SVG, or Canvas 2D, or WebGL. The code for doing the animation won't change.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to do it is give your projectile a starting position, velocity and acceleration. Then the position of the projectile at any time is position + velocity * time + acceleration * time * time. The angle of the projectile would just be the angle of the projectile's current velocity.

If you want to eventually adding other stuff like collisions then its probably a good idea to make the projectile track its current velocity and acceleration; and on each frame the position and velocity changes based on the elapsed time between each frame. Like so:

```
Projectile.prototype.update = function(dt){
     this.velocity += this.acceleration * dt;
     this.position += this.velocity * dt;
     this.angle = getAngle(this.velocity);
};
```

And on each frame, call `projectile.update(dt)` where `dt = currentFrameTime - lastFrameTime`.